# Make a clickable area unclickable once it's been clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, event-listener

As the title says, I'm trying to make clickable areas on my canvas 'unclickable'. I have multiple of these areas, and they're acting as buttons. They run functions which displays an image when clicked. What I want to do is make it so that when one of these areas is clicked, it can't be clicked again, but the others still can (until they have been clicked too).

Here's how the buttons work. I'm defining a clickable area like so:

```
    var rect = {
        x: 50,
        y: 180,
        width: 150,
        height: 133
    };
```

And I'm using an Event Listener to see if that area is clicked:

```
    canvas.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
        var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
        debugger;
        if (isInside(mousePos, rect)) {

            safeOpen.onload = function () {
                ctx3.drawImage(safeOpen, 50, 180, 150, 133);
            };
            safeOpen.src = imageArray[4];
        }


        if (isInside(mousePos, rect2)) {

            safeOpen.onload = function () {
                ctx3.drawImage(safeOpen, 220, 180, 150, 133);
            };
            safeOpen.src = imageArray[4];
        }


        if (isInside(mousePos, rect3)) {

            safeOpen.onload = function () {
                ctx3.drawImage(safeOpen, 390, 180, 150, 133);
            };
            safeOpen.src = imageArray[4];
        }
    } false);
```

The isInside function:

```
    function isInside(pos, rect, rect2, rect3, ) {
        return pos.x > rect.x && pos.x < rect.x + rect.width && pos.y < rect.y + rect.height && pos.y > rect.y
        return pos.x > rect2.x && pos.x < rect2.x + rect2.width && pos.y < rect2.y + rect2.height && pos.y > rect2.y
        return pos.x > rect3.x && pos.x < rect3.x + rect3.width && pos.y < rect3.y + rect3.height && pos.y > rect3.y
    }
```

Comment: Show us the *inside* of `isInside` and the structure of `rectX`. A simple way would be to attach a `.clicked` flag on each `rectX` object, and in `isInside` return false if this flag is `true`. Also, what you are doing with this `safeOpen` image is bad. Load all your images once before you start your app, store them in an object or array, and don't ever change their `src` during the whole life of your app.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I added the isInside code at the end of my question for you.